# Как обновить в таблице сотни тысяч строк? - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, update

имеется такая таблица:

```
┌──────┬──────────────────────┬────┐
│ Path │ Name                 │ id │
├──────┼──────────────────────┼────┤
│ 0    │ D:\1.bat             │ 1  │
│ 0    │ D:\Nichrome.rar      │ 2  │
│ 0    │ C:\pagefile.sys      │ 3  │
│ 0    │ E:\Уроки вождения.avi│ 4  │
│ 0    │ D:\$RECYCLE.BIN      │ 5  │
└──────┴──────────────────────┴────┘
```

нужно второй столбец разбить на составляющие и привести к такому виду:

```
┌──────┬──────────────────────┬────┐
│ Path │ Name                 │ id │
├──────┼──────────────────────┼────┤
│ D:\  │ 1.bat                │ 1  │
│ D:\  │ Nichrome.rar         │ 2  │
│ C:\  │ pagefile.sys         │ 3  │
│ E:\  │ Уроки вождения.avi   │ 4  │
│ D:\  │ $RECYCLE.BIN         │ 5  │
└──────┴──────────────────────┴────┘
```

проблема заключается в том, что строк около 800 тысяч, а на пхп оператором UPDATE построчно исправлять, за 5 минут(больше в IIS не знаю где настроить, все настройки игнорит) получается только 32000 строки, не знаю как в 1 запрос внести сразу несколько сотен строк, как в случае с оператором INSERT, скрипт без запросов UPDATE к базе обходит все 800 тысяч строк всего за 40 сек.
Может есть умы, которые смогут помочь? уже мысль всё это дело в CSV выгружать и лопатить через файл, думаю в разы быстрее получится

Comment: Т.е. тупо первые 3 символа в другую колонку ? тогда `update tab set path=substr(name,1,3), name=substr(name,4)` только перед этим проверьте с помощью select что эти substr дают действительно то, что ожидаете

Comment: @Mike вы же видите, что поля называются `path` и `filename`, а не `drive` и что-то еще.

Comment: в чем проблема сделать запрос непосредственно к БД, минуя пхп в принципе как ненужное звено в данном вопросе?

Comment: @teran Если бы я считал, что все действительно так просто я бы написал ответ, а не коммент. Я написал как оно могло бы быть если бы данные были такими, ожидая, что ТС увидя это приведет другие примеры данных и более точно сформулирует задачу.

Comment: Можно еще добавить условие WHERE `Path` = 0. В этом случае, если прервется выполнение запроса, то его можно повторно запустить и он продолжиться с места прерывания, так как после выполнения ячейка не будет равна 0

Comment: да, столбец содержит не только букву диска, а полный путь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не стоит выполнять UPDATE-запросы в цикле, более того, возможно стоит отказаться от выполнения такой задачи из PHP. Лучше всего выполнить такое преобразование при помощи чистого SQL при помощи одного UPDATE-запроса. Предположим, что вы имеете дело только с Windows-путями и разделителем у вас всегда выступает слеш. В этом случае задача сводится к поиску последнего слеша в подстроке Name и помещению всего что слева от него в `Path`, а все что справа от него в `Name`. Выполнить эту задачу можно при помощи следующего запроса:

```
UPDATE
  pathes
SET
  Path = SUBSTRING(Name, 1, LENGTH(Name) - LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, '\\', -1))),
  Name = SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, '\\', -1);
```

Если отказаться от PHP нет никакой возможности, возможно стоит выполнить этот запрос в несколько приемов, контролируя выполнено преобразование или нет при помощи конструкции `WHERE` и ограничивая количество обрабатываемых за раз строк при помощи `LIMIT`.

```
UPDATE
  pathes
SET
  Path = SUBSTRING(Name, 1, LENGTH(Name) - LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, '\\', -1))),
  Name = SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, '\\', -1)
WHERE
  Path <> '0'
LIMIT
  50000;
```

Это позволит не блокировать таблицу на слишком длительное время и последовательно преобразовать весь массив данных.

Comment: Спасибо, это то что нужно, c MySql сталкиваюсь постольку-поскольку, поэтому не знаю всех тонкостей запросов, цикличный апдейт через пхп вообще ужасно тормозная штука, а этот запрос вообще вещь ! теперь буду углубляться в изучение самого MySql :)